# PCA: How to add names to sample distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

In samples distribution graphs instead of the names (given in first columns) the numerical number 1 , 2, 3, 4 are provided for seasons. I have total six columns (Season    Annelida    Decapoda    Gastropoda  Isopoda Pisces).

```
    mydata<- read.csv("IRI_diet.csv", TRUE, ",")
mydata[is.na(mydata)]=0
attach(mydata)
X=cbind (Annelida, Decapoda, Gastropoda, Isopoda, Pisces)
summary(X)
cor(X)
res.pca <- prcomp (X, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
summary(res.pca)

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,
             col.ind = "cos2", # Color by the quality of representation
             gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
             repel = TRUE     # Avoid text overlapping
)
```

**Here is plot**

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIvlk.jpg):

Comment: Using the `iris` dataset I get variable names on the plot. Please, could you share your `IRI_diet.csv` file ?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your data. But if you're getting integers instead of words, that suggests you have a factor variable, and you're plotting the number of the level, rather than the label of the level

Comment: Thanks for the comments. From this link you can download my data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOgRDlF3_8evfmmJ-Kot7f0O2WvvJchW/view?usp=sharing